# Locking table with multiple users in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, locking

I have a MYSQL table built that has a table with a countdown so that as one user takes a resource the value in the table is decremented by 1 eventually going to zero. My code is below. 
The problem is that when I have multiple users accessing the site and decrementing the table, we get to a point where it should stop at zero, however, it manages to decrement below zero and go into minus numbers. 
I thought by applying locking the table (code below) the system would stop going to below zero. it seems though that locking doesn't lock the table. it appears like other users have a lock on the table also. anyone have any ideas on this? Also, would anyone have any Ideas on how I would test this? 
Thanks P

```
    //Lock Tables
    $query2 = "LOCK TABLES $_GET[ModuleCode]_students WRITE";
    sql_function($query2);
    $query = "insert into $_GET[ModuleCode]_students (Qualification,StudentNo,StudentSurname,StudentForename,StudentEmail,Grp,regesterTime) values  ('$_POST[Qualification]','$_POST[StudentNo]','$_POST[StudentSurname]','$_POST[StudentForename]','$_POST[StudentEMail]','$_POST[mygroup]',NOW())";

    sql_function($query);

    //check the number of places left with the lock on so it won't allow input into the table if at zero
    calc_placesleft();

    write_results($_POST[StudentNo],$_GET[ModuleCode],$_POST[mygroup]);

    Release lock on table $_GET[ModuleCode] 
    $query3 = "UNLOCK TABLES";

    sql_function($query3);
```

Comment: You need to post the source of `calcplacesleft` and `write_results` because from this code it doesn't look like you are checking the number of remaining places before writing.

Comment: What storage engine are the tables using? btw it looks like the code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks

Comment: @Nick Thanks... I'm having a look at 'calcplacesleft' and there is sql writes in there, I wonder do they need to be locked also. so does everything get locked when you enter the locked state? as in the functions getting locked.

Comment: @SpacePhoenix The datebase engine is MyISAM

Comment: You might want to have a look at the Innodb storage engine and the use of transactions